# Why won't this php SELECT FROM query work?

Tags: php

Here is my simple php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "********";  //hiding my password
   $dbname = "course";
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }

   $sql = "SELECT name FROM tutors";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if( $result === true ) {
     echo "good";
   } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row["name"];
   }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

In my database called "course", I have a table called "tutors" which has a column called "name". I have two entries in that table with the names "deep thought" and "pyrenees" respectively.

When this code runs however, the only thing that prints out is:

Error: SELECT name FROM tutors

It is supposed to simply print out the two names that I mentioned before.

Does anyone know why this happens? I know for a fact that I have the two entries in my table!

Comment: Try adding a if statement to catch the SQL error, `if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} `

Comment: Well, `->query()` returns a result object for successful `SELECT` queries, not `true`. Hence the condition is not fulfilled. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues . And that makes sense, otherwise how would you be able to do `$result->fetch_assoc()`, if `$result` was `true`? I guess you want `$result !== false` instead.

Comment: @FelixKling I see what you're saying and I have noted it. That explains why the error message shows up, but that isn't my main concern. My main concern is why the names within my database won't print even though my table is not empty.

Comment: What does `printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);` say?

Comment: Even though the success test is wrong, this should still print the rows, because he doesn't exit the script when printing the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word "name" is a MySQL [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-N). Wrap your query variables in <del>a tilde</del> backticks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `tutors`";
```

This helps to escape those values from MySQL thinking you're trying to referencing a built in variable.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use mysqli like so:

```
function getFollowers($link, $userid)
    {

        $sql = "SELECT users.id, username, profileImg FROM following INNER JOIN users ON users.id = following.userid WHERE followid = " . $userid;

        $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

        $resultsArray = [];

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $resultsArray[] = $row;

        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);

        return $resultsArray;
    }
```

This is just a clean example, I am sure you get the idea.

Here is what $link is

```
function connection()
    {
        define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
        define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
        define('DB_NAME', 'databaseTable');

        $link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        if($link === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        return $link;
    }
```

Or without the methods:

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
            define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
            define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
            define('DB_NAME', 'databaseTable');

            $link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

            if($link === false){
                die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

        $sql = "SELECT name FROM tutors";

        $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

        $resultsArray = [];

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            echo $row["name"];

        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);
```

To check if the query was successful you can do this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    //has rows, so whatever you want with them.
}
```

You put the condition after defining $result.

Comment: Where is your check for whether the query succeeded? That's the whole point of the question.